# How to fix "Call to a member function getUser()" in facebook via CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I am sitting in my chair for 2 hours and I cannot find what is wrong with this. I'm new to codeigniter things and I only got this error for the first time. Can you guys help me? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance so much ...

```
****A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Facebook_model::$facebook
Filename: models/facebook_model.php
Line Number: 15
Fatal error: *Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\hpbge\hpbge_files\system\hpbgestrong text_web_app\models\facebook_model.php on line 15*****


<?php
```

class Facebook_model extends Model {

```
public function get_user() {

    $query = $this->facebook->getUser();


    if ($query) {

        $data['is_true'] = TRUE;

        $data['facebook_uid'] = $query;

        return $data;

    } else {

        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;

        return $data;

    }

}



function get_access_token() {

    $query = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();



    if ($query) {

        $data['is_true'] = TRUE;

        $data['access_token'] = $query;

        return $data;

    } else {

        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;

        return $data;

    }

}



function get_api_secret() {

    $query = $this->facebook->getApiSecret();



    if ($query) {

        $data['is_true'] = TRUE;

        $data['api_secret'] = $query;

        return $data;

    } else {

        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;

        return $data;

    }

}



function get_app_id() {

    $query = $this->facebook->getApiSecret();



    if ($query) {

        $data['is_true'] = TRUE;

        $data['app_id'] = $query;

        return $data;

    } else {

        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;

        return $data;

    }

}



function get_logout_url() {

    $query = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => base_url()));



    if ($query) {

        $data['is_true'] = TRUE;

        $data['logout_url'] = $query;

        return $data;

    } else {

        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;

        return $data;

    }

}



function get_signed_request() {

    $query = $this->facebook->getSignedRequest();



    if ($query) {

        $data['is_true'] = TRUE;

        $data['signed_request'] = $query;

        return $data;

    } else {

        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;

        return $data;

    }

}



function set_access_token($access_token) {

    $query = $this->facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);



    if ($query) {

        $data['is_true'] = TRUE;

        return $data;

    } else {

        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;

        return $data;

    }

}



function set_api_secret($app_secret) {

    $query = $this->facebook->setApiSecret($app_secret);



    if ($query) {

        $data['is_true'] = TRUE;

        return $data;

    } else {

        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;

        return $data;

    }

}



function set_app_id($app_id) {

    $query = $this->facebook->setAppId($app_id);



    if ($query) {

        $data['is_true'] = TRUE;

        return $data;

    } else {

        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;

        return $data;

    }

}



//function is formatted for the following

//https://graph.facebook.com/ID/CONNECTION_TYPE?access_token=123456

function get_facebook_object($object, $facebook_uid, $access_token) {

    $fb_connect = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($fb_connect, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebook_uid.'/'.$object.'?access_token='.$access_token);  

    curl_setopt($fb_connect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  

    $output = curl_exec($fb_connect);  

    curl_close($fb_connect);  



    $result = json_decode($output);



    if (isset($result->error)) {

        $data['is_true'] = FALSE;

        $data['message'] = $result->error->message;

        $data['type'] = $result->error->type;

        $data['code'] = $result->error->code;



        return $data;

    } else {

        $data['is_true'] = TRUE;

        $data['data'] = $result->data;



        return $data;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please post your `facebook_model.php` code, especially around line 15.

Comment: I notice you never assign any values to `$this->facebook` object. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not loaded the facebook library put this line in your construct of model file

```
$this->load->library('facebook', array(
'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET'
));
```

and make sure that you have put the facebook.php and base_facebook.php in libraries folder under application.

Comment: Whoa ... I noticed it.. Well because I put this code 

<pre>
$this->load->library('facebook', array(
'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET'
));

into config folder... But thanks :) I actually did it just now. hah!
<code>